# Why can't I use my custom loadouts in training?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Whenever I start a training match against bots, the item server doesn't work and I can't access my loadouts.

I've tried everything I can think of, such as the heartbeat command, restarting TF2, reconnecting, and even waiting a few days.

Comment: Is this server set up with the default port? If it is not, then the port you used may be causing the server to interfere with the connection between your client and the server. (And even if it is a "local offline game", it is still set up as a server, just not available for anyone but you to join.)

Answer (score 1):

Listen servers are currently bugged - I would recommend trying a dedicated server, but that may be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Is there a source that confirms this?

Comment: @Robotnik I don't have an official source but I just created a local listen server and was not able to use a custom loadout.